# figure created by dirtree in one of the tabular cell

Tags: tables, dirtree

I wish to put a text-list and a `figure` made using `dirtree` side-by-side. So I am using tabular environment, in one cell I am putting `itemized` list and in other the `figure` environment. It does not work. Sample code below:

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{@{} p{0.35\linewidth} | p{0.6\linewidth}@{}} 

    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=2pt,parsep=2pt,partopsep=2pt,leftmargin=*]
    \item something
    \end{itemize}

&

\begin{figure}%[htp]
\dirtree{%
.1 Sheet Metal Features.
.2 Principal Features.
.3 Face-Wall   \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorWall.png}}.
.3 Bend   \qquad \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorBend.png}}.
.3 Flange  \quad \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorFlange.png}}.
.3 Loft Flange  \qquad \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorLoftedFlange.png}}.
%.3 Rib \quad \quad  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[height=0.11\linewidth]{..//Common/images/Feature_Rib.png}}.
}
\caption{Sheet Metal features}
\label{tax_sm}
\end{figure}
\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You can't have a `figure` environment inside a `tabular`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `figure` is a floating environment and, as such, can not be embedded inside a `tabular`.

You can give it a caption through the command `\captionof` provided by the `capt-of` package.

MWE

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[h]{@{} p{0.35\linewidth} | p{0.6\linewidth}@{}}

    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=2pt,parsep=2pt,partopsep=2pt,leftmargin=*]
    \item something
    \end{itemize}

&

\dirtree{%
.1 Sheet Metal Features.
.2 Principal Features.
.3 Face-Wall   \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorWall.png}}.
.3 Bend   \qquad \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorBend.png}}.
.3 Flange  \quad \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorFlange.png}}.
.3 Loft Flange  \qquad \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{..//Common/images/InventorLoftedFlange.png}}.
%.3 Rib \quad \quad  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[height=0.11\linewidth]{..//Common/images/Feature_Rib.png}}.
}
\captionof{figure}{Sheet Metal features}
\label{tax_sm}
\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]